# -bash: express: command not found after installing express and express-generator with NPM

Tags: node.js, bash, express, npm

I have a server with NodeJS and NPM already installed. 
Then process to install Express with NPM:

```
$ npm install express -g
```

It answered:

```
root@server ~ $ npm install express -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/depd/0.4.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/parseurl
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/on-finished
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/1.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/path-to-regexp/0.1.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/media-typer/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/proxy-addr
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/2.2.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/serve-static
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.9.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/type-is
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vary
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/on-finished
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/merge-descriptors/0.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/finalhandler/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/etag
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/1.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/depd/0.4.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/proxy-addr
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/serve-static
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/type-is
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/media-typer/0.3.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.9.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/2.2.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/vary
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/merge-descriptors/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/finalhandler/0.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/etag
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/parseurl
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/path-to-regexp/0.1.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ee-first/1.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/crc/3.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/0.4.9
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forwarded
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ipaddr.js/0.1.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.6.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/destroy/1.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forwarded
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/0.4.9
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ipaddr.js/0.1.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/crc/3.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ee-first/1.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.6.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/destroy/1.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-db
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-db
express@4.9.8 /var/www/site/npm/lib/node_modules/express
├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── cookie@0.1.2
├── fresh@0.2.4
├── escape-html@1.0.1
├── range-parser@1.0.2
├── cookie-signature@1.0.5
├── finalhandler@0.2.0
├── vary@1.0.0
├── media-typer@0.3.0
├── methods@1.1.0
├── parseurl@1.3.0
├── serve-static@1.6.4
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3
├── depd@0.4.5
├── qs@2.2.4
├── debug@2.0.0 (ms@0.6.2)
├── on-finished@2.1.0 (ee-first@1.0.5)
├── proxy-addr@1.0.3 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@0.1.3)
├── etag@1.4.0 (crc@3.0.0)
├── send@0.9.3 (destroy@1.0.3, ms@0.6.2, mime@1.2.11)
├── accepts@1.1.2 (negotiator@0.4.9, mime-types@2.0.2)
└── type-is@1.5.2 (mime-types@2.0.2)
```

and also

```
$ npm install express-generator -g
```

It answered:

```
root@server ~ $ npm install express-generator -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/1.3.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.5.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.5.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/1.3.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/-/minimist-0.0.8.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/-/minimist-0.0.8.tgz
/var/www/site/npm/bin/express -> /var/www/site/npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
express-generator@4.9.0 /var/www/site/npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator
├── commander@1.3.2 (keypress@0.1.0)
└── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
```

and all good up here, at least I no errors.
Now the problem arises when I want to use express:

```
$ express myapp
```

It answered:

```
-bash: express: command not found
```

Usually this problem occurs when there is express-generator was installed, and the install is solved, but it is not me =(. If anyone has any idea what I can do, will thank you.

NodeJS version: v0.11.13-pre 
NPM Version: 1.4.6

Ps: All these commands I ran as the root

Ps2: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What was the output from `npm install express-generator -g`? It should have showed what path it installed to.

Comment: Please don't change the case (`Express` vs. `express`) when quoting error messages. Case is significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing express-generator, we see

```
/var/www/site/npm/bin/express -> /var/www/site/npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
```

Add `/var/www/site/npm/bin` to your $PATH